# managing ssh command in a bash loop

Tags: bash, ssh, debian

i've done a bash script like this

while read site address
do
  ssh $address "df -k"
done

to repeat the remote command few times, but the loop works just once.
Any idea on the reason of this behavior? Did i miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-n` flag:

```
while read site address; do ssh -n $address "df -k";done
```

This tells `ssh` to leave `stdin` alone. Otherwise it will interfere with the next `read` command.